# C++ static library spaghetti

Tags: c++, static-linking

Suppose I have a first library called libA. I have 2 versions of libA. The first version is staticly linked in a project called libB.

I have another project which is an executable that contains libA (other version) and libB.

libB needs an older version of libA.

My question is: what will happen when I call a function in libA? How does the compiler know which libA version to call?

Comment: I would expect the linker to complain about duplicate symbols.

Comment: @drescherjm: Depending on the linker, there may be no errors. Static libraries are just containers of object files, from where they are picked as needed. If every undefined symbol is satisfied by the objects in one lib, then the other may never be linked in and no duplicate error would happen.

Comment: Static libraries do not depend on each other. Make a real example and better try to build it before asking here.

Comment: I think there's no way to solve your problem using static linking, at least with the versions of C++ I'm familiar with.

Comment: Is `libB` actually *dynamically* linked to the executable? I.E. is it a DLL?

Comment: No, in fact it is two versions of opencv for iOS. It is a .a library

Comment: i link everything staticly